# Suppress "file does not exist" error of svn remove

Tags: bash, svn, shell

In my project I have a folder with resources which I don't want to manually add or remove to the repository as I add or remove them to my working copy.

I wrote a simple bash script that checks `svn state` and calls `svn add` for files marked with a `?` and `svn remove` for files with a `!`. I added this bash script to my build script. The problem is, `svn remove` returns an error when called with a file that doesn't exist locally anymore. This results in my build script being aborted and returning an error too.

Is there a way to suppress these errors? I tried `--force` and `--quiet`. Didn't help.

Example:

```
MacBook-Pro:proj Bill$ echo "test" > foo.bar
MacBook-Pro:proj Bill$ svn st
?       foo.bar
MacBook-Pro:proj Bill$ svn add foo.bar 
A         foo.bar
MacBook-Pro:proj Bill$ rm foo.bar 
MacBook-Pro:proj Bill$ svn st
!       foo.bar
MacBook-Pro:proj Bill$ svn rm foo.bar
D         foo.bar
svn: 'foo.bar' does not exist
```

Comment: I'm using svn version 1.6.17 on OS X 10.7. I updated my post with an example. If there is no standard way to do this with svn, I think I'll just send `stderr` to `/dev/null`.

Comment: Well that didn't help either. I guess the problem isn't the error message itself, but the return value of `svn rm`.

Comment: `--keep-local` did the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are (at least) two different cases in which `svn stat` prints a line with an exclamation point:

1. The file exists in the repository, does not exist in the working directory, and `svn rm` was not used.
2. The file does not exist in the repository, `svn add` was used on the file, and the file does no longer exist in the working directory.

`svn rm` works in the first case, but exits with an error in the second case. There are several ways to solve this issue - depending on what you want to achieve:

- If you want to remove the file in both cases, do:
   `touch "$filename" ; svn rm --force "$filename"`.
- If you want to remove the file only in the second case, and revert in the first case, do:
   `svn revert "$filename"`.

Comment: Thanks, that's an even more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3):

So, to answer my question, using `--keep-local` fixed the problem.

Here is the script I ended up using. This will check for files marked as not versioned (`?`) and call `svn add` for them. Then it checks for files marked as missing (`!`) and call `svn rm` for them.

```
svn st "$Resources" | grep '^?' | sed 's_^?       \(.*\)$_svn add "\1"_g' | sh
svn st "$Resources" | grep '^!' | sed 's_^!       \(.*\)$_svn rm --keep-local  "\1"_g' | sh
```